# Is there any research on control of hidden stochastic processes?

Tags: time-series

**The short question:**

Are there any studies of systems described by several hidden stochastic time dependent variables and observed variables that are given by known deterministic functions of hidden variables?

**More Details:**

I have a time dependent stochastic process in which $n$ real-valued variables depend on time: $x_i(t)$. These variables cannot be observed directly ($i.e.$ they are hidden variables). However, we can observe a deterministic (not stochastic) function of these hidden variables: $y(t) = y(x_{i}(t))$ (in my particular case $y(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}(t)$). Moreover, we can observe another variable that is a function of hidden variables. This second function is also deterministic but it combines hidden variables corresponding to different times: $z(t) = x_{0}(t) + x_{1}(t-\Delta t) + x_{2}(t-2 \Delta t) + ... + x_{n}(t-n \Delta t)$.

In addition to that we know that subsequent vectors representing the hidden variables are related in a stochastic way: $x_{i}(t) = \psi[x_{i}(t - \Delta t)]$. The exact form of $\psi$ is not known.

We also always know $x_0(t)$ and we set the value of $x_{n}(t)$.

The goal is to find the stochastic relation $\psi$ and to chose such values of $x_{n}(t)$ that $x_{t}=0$ (we choose $x_{n}$ now and what to keep $x_{0}=0$ in the future). We also want to avoid $y=0$.

My question is how to approach this problem and if there are some results for such systems (or what are the name of such systems).

The closest that I can think of are Markov hidden process but, as you can see, it is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Marco: Look up the Literature on Optimal Control. Mostly in Electrical Engineering. This sounds so much like one of the Control System Design Problems.

If I may ask, what's the physical model behind your problem. Some context, if it is not confidential?